# Example of two star shaped polygons on the plane such that every edge of the first polygon is intersected by every edge of the second one internally

Tags: geometry, polygons

This question was asked in my computational geometry exam yesterday. The definition of a star shaped polygon was given as: *A polygon is called star-shaped if there is a point inside it such that the whole boundary is visible from that point*.

Since every edge of the first polygon must intersect every edge of the second, I first arranged the edges in a grid. I then connected them in a shark teeth fashion. But I couldn't manage to close the ends while still maintaining the intersection criteria. Any ideas on how this could be done?

[image]

Comment: I spent a lot of time thinking about this question yesterday and within 5 minutes of posting this I got the solution. How strange ^_^. Try and figure it out if you like to!

Comment: Not sure this site is meant to provide puzzles to people that are coming in here in search of answers ;-)

Comment: @YePhIcK Yeah I deleted it after I realized the solution but then thought of keeping it posted anyway ^v^.  Thought it was interesting enough to not be in a deleted state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mind if I answer my own question :)

The trick is to literally "close the ends". And pick  fewer lines, it'll be simpler to depict.

[image]

As you can see, the polygons are star shaped and the edges mutually fully intersect.